# Unable to join pandas dataframe second time in jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm adding two new `SMA` columns to my dataframe using the `pandas.DataFrame.join` function.

first time it's working fine but if I run that cell again I'm receiving the following error:

`ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['SMA_LONG'], dtype='object')`

Following is my code.

```
#cell 1
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#cell 2
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'close': np.random.uniform(0.1,0.9, 100),
})

#cell 3
SMA_long = 12
SMA_short = 7
sma_long = df['close'].rolling(window=SMA_long, min_periods=SMA_long - 1).mean()
df = df.join(sma_long.to_frame('SMA_LONG'))

sma_short = df['close'].rolling(window=SMA_short, min_periods=SMA_short - 1).mean()
df = df.join(sma_short.to_frame('SMA_SHORT'))

df.tail()
```

How I can fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error means there is already `SMA_LONG` before `df = df.join(sma_long.to_frame('SMA_LONG'))`.

---

For me working nice your sample data solution, but I think you can simplify it by assign to new columns:

```
SMA_long = 12
SMA_short = 7
df['SMA_LONG'] = df['close'].rolling(window=SMA_long, min_periods=SMA_long - 1).mean()
df['SMA_SHORT'] = df['close'].rolling(window=SMA_short, min_periods=SMA_short - 1).mean()

print (df)
       close  SMA_LONG  SMA_SHORT
0   0.649439       NaN        NaN
1   0.332926       NaN        NaN
2   0.492527       NaN        NaN
3   0.500444       NaN        NaN
4   0.583334       NaN        NaN
..       ...       ...        ...
95  0.775169  0.532850   0.577613
96  0.470479  0.524123   0.594733
97  0.237417  0.517054   0.512506
98  0.753701  0.536595   0.554372
99  0.133795  0.526603   0.475595

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Or:

```
sma_long = df['close'].rolling(window=SMA_long, min_periods=SMA_long - 1).mean()
sma_short = df['close'].rolling(window=SMA_short, min_periods=SMA_short - 1).mean()

df = df.assign(SMA_LONG=sma_long, SMA_SHORT=sma_short)
```

Comment: @Unnikrishnan - You can so it, but then necessary `lsuffix` parameter - if need oroginal column `SMA_LONG` and new column `SMA_LONG` - it add to original left prefix .

Comment: like `df = df.join(sma_short.to_frame('SMA_LONG'), lsuffix='orig')`